# Coding japanese characters in a google API search string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, unicode

I am trying to perform searches in Japanese using the custom google search api as follows:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class Search
  include HTTParty
  format :json
end

@response = Search.get('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=etcetc&q=JAPANESE SEARCH TERM')
```

When Japanese text is used it fails complaining of "invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)"

How can I input Japanese text in a format which Ruby allows and google custom api also accepts?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

to the top of the file

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up google api may still not accept these Japanese search terms - it's very simple to escape them and use them in your search by using URI.escape

```
require 'uri' 
retVal = URI.escape("Japanese term", Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))
```